# Determine the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1-(-2)^{(-k-1)}k!}{k!} (z-2)^k$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I could use some help solving this one. Applying the nth-root or the ratio test didn't work out for me.

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1-(-2)^{(-k-1)}k!}{k!} (z-2)^k$$

Hints are just as appreciated as solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: split the sum into two parts: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(z-2)^k$ which converges absolutely everywhere (ratio test), and $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty -(-2)^{-k-1}(z-2)^k$.  This should make things easier.

Comment: I can only split the sum into two parts if both newly created parts converge. Can I do this only knowing (afterwards) that the second sum only converges for a radius of 2?

Comment: You can because one of the parts converges absolutely for all values of $z$.  Certainly the splitting works whenever you are in the radius of convergence of the second series (so no problem there).  The only possible trouble is when you are outside the radius of convergence of the second series: can adding them together cause the whole sum to converge?  The answer is no; if it did, you could add the *negative* of the first sum to the combined sum (adding two convergent series) and so the second series would have to converge, too.

Comment: Say I have a series which I split into two series again. The first one has a radius of 4 and the second a radius of 2. I can then deduce that the radius of convergence for the actual series is 2, right? The minimum of the radius' always the one I'm looking for because outside of it only one of the series would converge.

Comment: Even that much detail is not really necessary in this case, though.  The second sum diverges really badly outside its radius of convergence -- the terms go to infinity in absolute value.  Since the terms of the first sum go to zero in absolute value, the terms of the total sum must still go to infinity in absolute value, so it diverges.

Comment: That's correct, though you need to be extra careful if the two sums have the *same* radius of convergence -- they might cancel each other out!

Comment: I am slightly confused now after your second comment, is there any way we can continue this conversation in chat? I don't have the privilege to create a chat but maybe you could invite me. It will only take 2-3 minutes, I believe. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11826/discussion-between-universalset-and-kitkat4-4)